# ISelectionListener Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have added a selection listener to one of my Editors in Eclipse. In Eclipse versions 4.1 and 4.2 the selection listener works when I move my cursor with the arrow keys. No text actually has to be selected. In version 3.7 I actually have to select text for the listener to work properly. Was there a change between 3.7 and 4.1? How can I get the same functionality in 3.7?

Comment: This could just be a difference between 3.x and 4.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. I removed the selection listener and added a caret listener to my editors. The caret listener appears to behave the same in 3.7, 4.1, and 4.2